# Variable not being remembered in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have some code that loops through a directory and retrieves the file name of each file. The code then retrieves the contents of each file (usually a number or a short text).

```
var config = {};
config.liveProcValues = {};


var path = require('path');
walk = function(dir, done) {
var results = {};
fs.readdir(dir, function(err, list) {
    if (err) return done(err);
    var pending = list.length;
    if (!pending) return done(null, results);
    list.forEach(function(file) {
        file = path.resolve(dir, file);
        fs.stat(file, function(err, stat) {
            if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
                walk(file, function(err, res) {
                    results = results.concat(res);
                    if (!--pending) done(null, results);
                });
            } else {


                fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8', function(err, data) {

                    if (err) {
                        contents = err;
                    } else {
                        contents = data;
                    }

                        console.log(filename + " - " + contents);


                    filename = file.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
                    config.liveProcValues[filename] = contents;


                });
```

The console.log line successfully outputs the right information, however when trying to store it into JSON:

```
  config.liveProcValues[filename] = contents;
```

It simply does remember the information.

```
walk("testdirectory", function(err, results) {
   if (err) throw err;
});

// Output the configuration
console.log(JSON.stringify(config, null, 2));
```

Comment: What do your filenames look like? Are you sure the pattern in `replace` doesn't result in an empty string?

Comment: When i run console.log on the filename it returns the correct value

Comment: @Felix King - why duplicate?

Comment: The file names are test1.txt and test2.txt

Comment: Because it explains the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: What explains the issue I am experiencing?

Comment: The duplicate. In your case the solution is rather simple: Move the `console.log` call inside the `walk` callback.

Comment: the console.log works fine.... its the config.liveProcValues[filename] = contents that doesn't work

Simply moving that into the walk call does not work

Comment: `config.liveProcValues[filename] = contents;` works just fine, but you are trying to log the object **before** `fs.readdir` is done. Another issue is that you are calling `results = results.concat(res);` but `results` is an object, so this will throw an error at some point. Yet another issue seems to be that you are not calling `done` if there are no sub-directories but only files.

Comment: Thanks - starting to understand now - how would I log it in a way that works?

Comment: The callback is supposed to be called when the file system was traversed. Anything that needs access to the result of the walk has to be inside or called from the callback. Then you just have to make sure that the callback really is called after you are done traversing (which currently is not the case). Look at the branches where you are calling `done`: Either if there are no files in the directory or if it contains a subdirectory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82604/discussion-between-corbin-and-felix-kling).

Comment: Wrote an answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that you are accessing the data **after** the filesystem was traversed. In order to do that you have to move the `console.log` *into* the `walk` callback:

```
walk("testdirectory", function(err, results) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // Output the configuration
  console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 2));
});
```

See [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) for more info.

That alone won't solve the issue though, since you have a couple of logic errors in your code. You are trying to treat an object as an array (`results.concat`) and you are not always calling `done` when you are done (in particular, you are not calling `done` after you finished reading the files in a directory).

---

Here is a version that should come closer do what you want.

This uses [**`Object.assign`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to merge two objects, which is not available in Node yet, but you can find modules that provide the same functionality.

Note thats I also removed the whole `config` object. It's cleaner if you work with `results`.

```
var path = require('path');
function walk(dir, done) {
  var results = {};
  fs.readdir(dir, function(err, list) {
    if (err) return done(err);
    if (!list.length) return done(null, results);

    var pending = list.length;
    list.forEach(function(file) {
      file = path.resolve(dir, file);
      fs.stat(file, function(err, stat) {
        if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
          walk(file, function(err, res) {
            if (!err) {
              // Merge recursive results
              Object.assign(results, res);
            }
            if (!--pending) done(null, results);
          });
        } else {
          fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            var contents = err || data;
            console.log(file + " - " + contents);
            file = file.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
            // Assign the result to `results` instead of a shared variable
            results[file] = contents;
            // Need to call `done` if there are no more files to read
            if (!--pending) done(null, results);
          });
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

---

But instead of writing your own `walk` implementation, you could also [use an existing package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/walk).